# Looping through all folders in FTP directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found some code online, and modified it to list all folders in an FTP directory.  I have all the folders listed, with the code below.

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
import datetime


filenames = []
data = []

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.something.com', 'u_name', 'pswd')  

def get_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    contents = ftp.nlst(folder)
    folders = []
    for item in contents:
        if "." not in item:
            folders.append(item)
    return folders
def get_all_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    dirs = []
    new_dirs = []
    new_dirs = get_dirs_ftp(folder)
    while len(new_dirs) > 0:
        for dir in new_dirs:
            dirs.append(dir)

        old_dirs = new_dirs[:]
        new_dirs = []
        for dir in old_dirs:
            for new_dir in get_dirs_ftp(dir):
                new_dirs.append(new_dir)
    dirs.sort()
    return dirs

allfiles = []
all_dirs = get_all_dirs_ftp()
```

Using the code above, I confirmed that the hierarchy is correct.  Now, I am trying to loop through this list of folders and subfolders, and drill down to the files in each.  This is where the problem occurs.  Here's the rest of my code.

```
for dir in all_dirs:
    ftp.cwd(dir)
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')  

    filenames = []  
    ftp.retrlines('NLST', filenames.append) 

    # writes file name and modified date and file size, to dataframe
    #data = []
    for filename in filenames:  
        filename
        modifiedTimeFtp = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime[4:], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        size = ftp.size(filename)
        filesize = "{:.2f}".format(size/(1024)) + 'kb'
        finaldata = (str(filename) + '|' + str(modifiedTimeFtp) + '|' + str(filesize))
        allfiles.append(finaldata,'\n')
```

Now, when I run this section of code, I get this error: `TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable`

I'm thinking that the problem lies in this range.

```
ftp.cwd(dir)
ftp.retrlines('LIST')  

filenames = []  
ftp.retrlines('NLST', filenames.append)
```

That's my guess, but I don't know for sure.  Is there an easy way to get this working?  I almost feel like this is mission impossible, because the FTP folder that I'm querying is pretty massive, and I'm guessing there can be all kinds of timeouts, or whatever, while the task is running.  All I'm trying to do is get the file name, file date/time modified, and file size.  Thanks for the look.

Comment: Do you have the url of an actual ftp site folks could use for testing?

Comment: I don't have access to a generic FTP directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final, working, version.

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
from datetime import datetime


filenames = []
data = []

ftp = ftplib.FTP('ftp.anything.com', 'u_name', 'ps_wd')  


def get_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    contents = ftp.nlst(folder)
    folders = []
    for item in contents:
        if "." not in item:
            folders.append(item)
    return folders
def get_all_dirs_ftp(folder=""):
    dirs = []
    new_dirs = []
    new_dirs = get_dirs_ftp(folder)
    while len(new_dirs) > 0:
        for dir in new_dirs:
            dirs.append(dir)

        old_dirs = new_dirs[:]
        new_dirs = []
        for dir in old_dirs:
            for new_dir in get_dirs_ftp(dir):
                new_dirs.append(new_dir)
    dirs.sort()
    return dirs

#allfiles = []
# get parent and child folders in directory
all_dirs = get_all_dirs_ftp()

# create a list to append metadata
dir_list = []

for dir in all_dirs:
    ftp.cwd('/'+dir+'/')
    print(dir)
    dir_list.append(dir)
    ftp.dir(dir_list.append)

    len(dir_list)


# you probably want to dump the results to a file...
outF = open('C:/your_path/filenames.csv', 'w')
for line in dir_list:
  # write line to output file
  outF.write(line)
  outF.write("\n")
outF.close()
print('Done!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the stacktrace for the actual line that is causing the error.

From your code the fault appears to be this line:

```
    modifiedTimeFtp = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetime[4:], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S").strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

`datetime` here appears to be the module, but you probably want to refer to some variable with the date, so `datetime[4:]` is causing the error.

Comment: I fixed the date issue.  Now I'm seeing this: AttributeError: 'FTP' object has no attribute 'changed'.  It must come from this line: ftp.cwd(dir)
I researched this.  That's definitely how you change the directory.  What I'm not sure of, is whether or not the system needs a '/' character.  there will be a bunch of files in this directory: 'zae4'.  Also, there will be files in this directory: 'zae4/daily'.  Likewise, there will be a bunch of files in this directory: 'zae4/model_receipt'.  I thought I could drill down into each sub-directory, but I'm guessing it doesn't actually work like that.

Comment: Oh, now I see...  It has to be like this:  
for dir in all_dirs:
    ftp.cwd('/'+dir+'/')

Then it works.  Woo hoo!!